# Different definitions of tensor fields

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors, vector-fields

I have come across two definitions of a smooth tensor field of type $(r,s)$ and I was wondering if someone could explain how they are equivalent.

**Definition 1:**
A smooth tensor field on a differentiable manifold $M$ of type $(r,s)$ is a map $A: C_r^\infty(TM)\rightarrow C_s^\infty(TM)$ which is multilinear over the commutative ring $C^\infty(M)$. Here, $C^\infty(TM)$ is the set of smooth vector fields on $M$, $C_r^\infty(TM)$ is the r-fold tensor product of $C^\infty(TM)$ over $C^\infty(M)$ and $C_0^\infty=C^\infty(M)$.

**Definition 2:** A smooth tensor field of type $(r,s)$ on a smooth manifold $M$ is a $C^\infty(M)$-multilinear map
$A: C^\infty(T^*M)\times ... \times C^\infty(T^*M) \times C^\infty(TM)\times ... \times C^\infty(TM) \rightarrow C^\infty (M)$,
so the product of $r$ covector fields and $s$ vector fields are being sent to $C^\infty(M)$.

Comment: I think your Definition 2 might be missing the word "multilinear," and your Definition 1 might want "linear" in place of "multlinear."  Separately: It sounds like your question boils down to a question about multilinear algebra.  Given a vector space $V$, the question is how a linear map $V^{\otimes r} \to V^{\otimes s}$ can be viewed as multilinear map $V^* \times \cdots \times V^* \times V \times \cdots \times V \to \mathbb{R}$, and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Yes, forgot to add ”multilinear” in the second definition. It is edited now.

Comment: By the universal property we can factor your second A uniquely through a multilinear function from product to tensor product. Use similar argument to "split" the tensor product into two products, apply the exponential objects definition to that product and you have a linear Cinf(r)->Cinf(s).

Comment: Note that smooth TFs on M form a module so tensor product is well defined.